# selenium Cucumber hash (ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am writing some testing features, I started with a table, then I changed data in the table and got a copy and wanted to start population a form from the hash, here is my code :

```
 Given /^I start with this table$/ do |table|
  @hashes = []
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
  Faker::Config.locale = 'en-US'
    hash['fname'] = "Joe"
  hash['lname'] = "Doe"

    @hashes << hash
  end
end
```

and the code that will populate the data form from the hash :

```
Then /^I can populate full name from the transformed data$/ do
  @hashes.each do |hash|
    puts hash
  end

  fname = $driver.find_element(:id,"applicant_first_name")
  fname.send_keys(@hashes['fname'])   <-- LINE 55

  lname = $driver.find_element(:id,"applicant_last_name")
  lname.send_keys(@hashes['lname'])

end
```

But I got this error :

no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
./features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb:55:in `[]'
./features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb:55:in`/^I can populate full name from the transformed data$/'
features/brc_epic03_emp_F_bulk_pp.feature:23:in `Then I can populate full name from the transformed data'

Thanks,

Comment: please share line `custom_steps.rb:55` and `brc_epic03_emp_F_bulk_pp.feature:23`

Comment: line 55 is in the code, I put <-- LINE 55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to see the cause of the problem if you narrow it down to a **Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable example.

The problem is that you are defining:

```
@hashes = [
  # ...
  { 
    # ...
    'fname' => "Joe",
    # ...
  },
  # ...
]
```

and then trying to access the value `"Joe"` via:

```
@hashes['fname']
```

This does not work, because `@hashes` is actually an **Array**. The error message:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

is saying that you can only look up an array element by its `Integer` index.

There are various ways you could fix this, such as explicitly using the *first* hash of user properties in your list. (I'd also recommend using a more descriptive variable name than `@hashes`, but that's a separate issue!)

```
Then /^I can populate full name from the transformed data$/ do
  @hashes.each do |hash|
    puts hash
  end

  fname = $driver.find_element(:id,"applicant_first_name")
  fname.send_keys(@hashes.first['fname']) # <-- !!!

  lname = $driver.find_element(:id,"applicant_last_name")
  lname.send_keys(@hashes.first['lname']) # <-- !!!
end
```